# Can't remove postgresql in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, postgresql

Im trying to remove entire postgresql on ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql*
```

Now it is not working anymore and i got this message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10.3-1-linux-x64.run
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-10.3-1-linux-x64.run'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-10.3-1-linux-x64.run'
```

Answer (score 0):

This command is wrong. The term `postgresql*` is taken as a pattern and expanded to the list of files whose name begin with `postgresql` in your current directory, if there are any.

By the error message, there is that file `postgresql-10.3-1-linux-x64.run`.

The closest correct command would be:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove 'postgresql*'
```